# COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used

Tags: c#, winforms, com, interop, multithreading

I have some COM component which I call from some c# dll.

I also have a winforms app that uses that .dll.

When I close the app I get this exception:

> COM object that has been separated
>   from its underlying RCW cannot be
>   used.

The stack trace shows this exception comes from a destructor in the .dll. I implemented this destructor to call some cleanup method in the COM.

Why does this happen? How is it best to solve it?

Comment: Read this: http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-com-interop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567017/com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-cannot-be-used)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The issue is described here:

[Is it safe to call an RCW from a finalizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573977/is-it-safe-to-call-an-rcw-from-a-finalizer)

and here:

[Release Excel Object In My Destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085972/release-excel-object-in-my-destructor)

> The trouble is that not only is the timing as to when these objects
>   are to be garbage collected uncertain, but the order in which the
>   finalizers are called is also nondeterministic. In this case, a
>   Runtime Callable Wrapper also has a finalizer, which calls
>   Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject on itself, which has the result of
>   decrementing the reference count on the COM side of the fence so that
>   this COM object can be released. But since the order in which the
>   finalizers are called is uncertain, it is very possible that the
>   finalizers for the COM objects that your object references will fire
>   before the finalizer for your object. So the code within your
>   finalizer could work sometimes, but, most of the time, one or more of
>   the Runtime Callable Wrappers that your object references will have
>   already had their finalizers called and the underlying COM object will
>   have been released before your finalizer gets to execute its code.

Comment: I did not follow a thing! :x

Comment: It's pretty clear: the COM wrapper around the object you instantiated might be cleaned up before you get around to cleaning it up yourself. Translation: If your Dispose() attempts to call Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject(x) when that underlying x has already gone out of scope, your Dispose() will fail.  Gotta check that scope/lifecycle.  Thanks for the good links, @Ran.