# Syntax error with Date in sql query

Tags: sql, vb.net

In my program I'm saving date from DateTimePicker into the global variable with 
`My.Settings.date = dtpDate_do.Value.Date`. I'm using this date to compare date from my database but I'm always getting syntax error, no matter what I'm changing.
This is my query:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, order_date FROM orders WHERE order_date = " & My.Settings.date & " ORDER BY ID DESC"
```

Dates in my database are stored in EU format with dots -  `17.2.2014`. Can anyone provide me some help.

Comment: Post your syntax error as well.

Comment: Syntax error is likely because there are no quotes around the date.

Comment: what do you get in My.Settings.date ? As in the actual value at runtime when you debug?

Comment: dear friend check the post bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever create your query like that. Always and without any exception use parameters. This avoids both SQL-injection attacts and ensures proper formatting of your parameters.

Sorry for not knowing VB.NET, but it should be similar to this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, order_date FROM orders WHERE order_date = @Date ORDER BY ID DESC" 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", My.Settings.data)
```

Explanation: Create your query using `@ParamName` as a placeholder for your parameters. Then substitute your parameters with values. Make sure to either apply a concrete typed value (i.e. not an object) or/and supply the data type otherwise.

Comment: Ty alzaimar. Your approach worked as planned. But now I'm getting another error on program startup. _COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used_. Do u have any idea what why is that happening?.

Comment: I've tried with local variables but there is still this error. Maybe is it caused somewhere in code ahead. Dunno.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260990/com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-cannot-be-used

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a parameter in the query like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, order_date FROM orders WHERE order_date = @date ORDER BY ID DESC";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date", dateTimePicker.Value.Date));
```