# COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used. in oledb

Tags: c#

I got this error and I don't know what I doing wrong. The code below is in the backrgoundworker.

Copy exception detail to the clipboard :

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException was unhandled
>   by user code   HResult=-2146233049   Message=COM object that has been
>   separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.StubRegisterRCW(Object pThis)
>          at System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAccessor.ReleaseAccessor(IntPtr
>   hAccessor, Int32& pcRefCount)
>          at System.Data.OleDb.RowBinding.Dispose()
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ResetConnection()
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>          at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
>          at AttendanceSystem.Student.frmNewStudent.bgwInsertStudent_DoWork(Object
>   sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\victorbaccaljr\Desktop\PROGRAM\Event Attendace
>   System\AttendanceSystem\AttendanceSystem\Student\frmNewStudent.cs:line
>   138
>          at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
>          at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object
>   argument)   InnerException:

code :

```
private void bgwInsertStudent_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<object> arg = (List<object>)e.Argument;
        bool found = false;
         using (OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select top 1 * from [student info] where id=@id";
                cmd.Connection = cnn;

                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", arg[0].ToString());

                cnn.Open();
                using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    rdr.Read();
                    if (rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        found = true;
                    }
                    cnn.Close();
                }
            }
            using(OleDbCommand cmd=new OleDbCommand())
            {
                if(found)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Student ID already inserted.");
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into [Student info] values(@id, @firstname, @lastname, @department, @address)";
                    cmd.Connection = cnn;

                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", arg[0].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", arg[1].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", arg[2].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", arg[3].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", arg[4].ToString());

                    cnn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cnn.Close();

                    MessageBox.Show("Record inserted!");

                    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not call `cnn.Close()`

Comment: And please post the actual code within your question, don´t use images as it´s impossible to find them in the search-engines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260990/com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-cannot-be-used)

Comment: Did you notice the *copy exception detail to the clipboard* link? You should try it. It offers all the info I might need without having to look at a screenshot. All I can do now is yell at my screen *click View Detail...*

Comment: already inserted the whole code in my backgroundworker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aspirin mentioned in the comment you shouldn´t call `Connection.Close` on your own. **But that´s not a general rule.** You´re right that the connection should be closed to free unmanaged resources like a connection to the database or file-handlers. However in your case as you have an enclosing `using`-block that will automatically call `Dipose` when the variable gets out of scope and thus will call `Connection.Close` this latter call is done twice causing the exception when you´re closing the connection yourself.

Your `using`-block would be similar to this:

```
OleDbConnection con;
try
{
   con = new OleDbConnection(...);
    // ...
   con.Close();
}
finally
{
    if(con != null) con.Close();
}
```

Causing `Close` to be called twice on a successful run.

So you can simply omit the call to `cnn.Close`. because it´s allready done implicietly.

Comment: Ok I got it. I forget the using(){} will automatically dispose the object.